# How to display web2py errors directly (auto redirect to ticket)

Tags: web2py

When developing a web2py application, its pretty normal to have various syntax errors, db issues and such.

However, when debugging these problems (in a non production system), a ticket link is presented by default, instead of the actual ticket.

Is there a way to auto redirect to the actual ticket , eliminating the need to click (and wait for the actual ticket to load)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding something like the following to your /web2py/routes.py file:

```
error_message_ticket='''
  <html><head>
    <script language="javascript">
      location.replace("/admin/default/ticket/%(ticket)s")
    </script>
    <!-- this is junk text else IE does not display the page: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx //-->
  </head></html>'''
```

For more details, see [Routes on Error](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Routes-on-Error) in the online book.